# Setting default order by controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

can someone please help me with this - probably - very noob question, please?

I have the following html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Starting Angular</title>
</head>
<!-- The ng-app directive triggers load and setup of AngularJS
     after the DOM is loaded.
     It sets the tag as the root of the AngularJS app.  -->
<body ng-app="cardApp">
    <!-- Identify the controller and model to be used. -->
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <!-- The ng-bind gets data from the model. -->
        <h1 ng-bind="greeting"></h1>
        <br />
        Sort by:
        <select ng-model="orderProp">
            <option value="suit">Suit</option>
            <option value="numOrd">Number</option>
        </select>

        <table>
            <tr><th>Number</th><th>Suit</th></tr>
            <!-- Populate the HTML with each object in the cards model. -->
            <tr ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:orderProp ">
                <td ng-bind ="card.number"></td>
                <td ng-bind ="card.suit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I would like to set the default order of the cards shown by number. How can I do that modifying this controller?

```
// Register controller with angular module.
var cardApp = angular.module('cardApp', []);

// The controller is a constructor function that takes a $scope parameter.
// The controller lets us establish data binding between the controller and the view.
// The model is initialized with the $scope parameter.
cardApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {$scope.val = "numOrd"
// Scope ensures that any changes to the 
// model are reflected in the controller.
// Here we create an initialize a 'title' model.
$scope.greeting = "AngularJS Hello World!";

// Define cards model which stores an array of objects.
$scope.cards = [
    { "number": "2", "suit": "Hearts", "numOrd": 2 },
    { "number": "10", "suit": "Spades", "numOrd": 10 },
    { "number": "5", "suit": "Spades", "numOrd": 5 },
    { "number": "Q", "suit": "Hearts", "numOrd": 12 }
    ];
}]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to change descending/ascending order?

Comment: Show your `orderProp` function

Comment: fellow BCIT student, I'm guessing?

Comment: @suvroc orderProp isn't a function as far as I can tell, unless within AngularJS itself, but at least in the minified version I couldn't find it anywhere. -- turns out orderProp is the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function 'sort' in Array class. It will sort your cards array.

```
array.sort([compareFunction])
```

In this case:

```
$scope.cards.sort(function(a, b){
  return a['numOrd'] - b['numOrd'];
});
```

More about 'sort': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

The other method is to extend your model with another properties `suitOrd` which assign each of your suit one specific number. Thanks to this you can sort by this property because it will be a number

Comment: I'm guessing you mean numOrd, right? cause I don't see suitOrd anywhere, and it does what you're talking about. - But then you just say "sort by this property" -- not knowing how to do that is exactly the problem here. Just replace orderProp with numOrd or what?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add this to your js.

```
$scope.orderProp = "numOrd";
```